# understanding scala generics from class signature

Tags: scala, generics

Recently I am looking into the internals of Spark SQL and met this core class TreeNode from package  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.

```
abstract class TreeNode[BaseType <: TreeNode[BaseType]] extends Product {
// scalastyle:on
  self: BaseType =>

  val origin: Origin = CurrentOrigin.get
```

Above is a small code segment of this class. I have provided the class name and package name so you can reference to, if more code segment needed I am glad to pin it.

I am not familiar with scala and find that it a bit difficult for me to understand this generics.
I have two questions regards this:

1. I think this generics suggest that TreeNode should contain a inner element which is the type or subtype of a TreeNode[BaseType]. But here what makes me confused is that the first BaseType is type or subtype of TreeNode[BaseType], but what about the second BaseType? Are there any restriction of type on it?
2. Since this class doesn't have an explicit constructor, I am not sure at which place does this compile check apply?  Also , I am not clear about what is the holder of this generic notion? By this I mean something like the Node<K,V> in the HashMap<K,V>. I traced down to the very subtype of it and see nothing like the holder at all.

Hope anyone could help clarify this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason for looking at the internals of **Spark**? It shouldn't be needed for using the framework. Also, the code of **Spark** must be one of the most complex and less idiomatic code bases out there, for a newcomer I do not see any good reason for diving deep in it.

Comment: Hi, I am quite interested in sql-on-hadoop and spark sql is an outstanding one. I know I  will stay for quite long time at the newcomer stage but my ultimate goal is to understand spark sql core and maybe could become a contributor later in several years. I just wanna learn scala program design in real-world project  rather than toy ones.

Comment: I know this may not be a good start point but I am not sure which one would be better one. Since scala has quite a few features which in toy projects less than 5% of them is not used or used in a proper way. I will really appreciate if you can suggest some better projects

Comment: **Spark** is not a real world **Scala** program, **Spark** is a real world legacy **Java** framework, but whatever. If your end goal is to become a **Spark** contributor then the best would be to learn basic **Scala** syntax _(which you probably already did)_ and then learn **Java** techniques and become familiar with OOP. Learn about inheritance, F-Bounded Polymorphism, reflection, etc. Also, then yes, look at the **Spark** code, I am pretty sure there is no similar project out there, also you ask to the project maintainers themselves what would be a good starting issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pattern called "F-bounded polymorphism." (As far as I can tell, nobody's really sure where the name comes from.)

```
// T must be a subtype of Entity[T]
trait Entity[T <: Entity[T]] { self: T =>
  //methods defined here
}
```

With this in place the compiler will enforce certain relationship patterns.

```
class A extends Entity[A]  <-- OK
class B extends Entity[A]  <-- won't compile
```

Comment: _"won't compile"_, well except that it is somewhat easy to break it. But well as long as you ensure by yourself that you do not break it _(like it was an untyped language)_, it works somewhat good.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I am not seeming the meaning of this polymorphism. `abstract class QueryPlan[PlanType <: QueryPlan[PlanType]] extends TreeNode[PlanType]` . This adds one more nest level I don't see what is the point of this. It just gives  me big confusion.

Comment: @BoyuZhang the point of **F-Bounded** polymorphism is allow a superclass to refer to the subclass and _"force"_ the subclass to pass itself. So `trait Parent[C <: Parent[C]]` and then `final class Child extends Parent[Child]`  this allows the parent class to refer to the child class which will be the typeparameter `C` and it also avoids that the child class can lie about it, so `Child extends Parent[String]` won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

1. A `TreeNode` doesn't "contain a inner element". It's only parametrised by some type, `BaseType`. `BaseType` also has to be a `TreeNode` parametrised by `BaseType`. So it has to be `TreeNode` parametrized with itself. E.g. `Expression extends TreeNode[Expression]`
2. Compile check takes place, well, at compile time. Constructor and class construction are not necessary. You don't even have to use the class in your code.

Comment: Thank a lot. But still I found it is quite confusing to me. Epescially when I saw TreeNode has a subtype like this `abstract class QueryPlan[PlanType <: QueryPlan[PlanType]] extends TreeNode[PlanType]`. What is the aim or benefits to have this kind of I mean nested generic? To me generic is kind of hint to compiler on the type but this one seems not explicit at all.